# How do I convert my Json Object (which can be nested) into '&' separated key value pairs?

Tags: java, json, form-data

I would like to know if there is any function in Java which does the same job as http_build_query in php. I found many similar questions but didn't find the solution I'm searching for.

For example :

If my JSON String looks like:

```
{
  "a": "b",
  "c": {
    "d": "e"
  },
  "f": {
    "g": {
      "h": "i"
    }
  }
}
```

I want the function to return  `a=b&c[d]=e&f[g][h]=i` .

Comment: what you did so far, post your code/tries

Comment: I can easily write a code which can do this for me but I want to know if there exists any function like in php